# "Rotate about" vs. "rotate around"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, prepositions

Is there a difference in meaning between

> This operation rotates the object about the axis defined by ...

and

> This operation rotates the object around the axis defined by ...

(e.g. in the context of a graphical user interface)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*[About](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/about)* and *[around](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/around)* are synonymous in this context; they are both valid and mean the same thing.

[Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rotate%20about,rotate%20around&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows us that *rotate* has been more commonly used with *about*, though in later years the two options seem to have become more equivalent in terms of popularity:

[image]

Comment: I think "About and around are synonymous in this context" isn't true.  The phrasing "rotates ... about the axis" is well-understood and well-defined mathematical terminology with specific meaning; the phrasing "rotates ... around the axis" is not, and as such may introduce doubt in the mind of any careful reader regarding what is meant.

Comment: Could you perhaps explain why *rotates ... around the axis* confuses the meaning?  I've heard and seen it a lot.

Comment: What I would rather do is delete my previous comment :) rather than try to substantiate it.  However, I find upon clicking on quotations at the given ngrams link (on the first pages of them, at least) that uses of "rotate about" seem precise, while uses of "rotate around" (except the first link) are not; eg: "You can allow the user to rotate around any single axis or pair of axes" (user rotates? or axis rotates?) and "the heavens are round everywhere and rotate around themselves" (how?).

Comment: @JamesWaldby-jwpat7   I don't understand what is the confusion you see in "You can allow the user to rotate around any single axis or pair of axes". What do you mean exactly by "user rotates? or axis rotates?" ?  How can you understand that the "axis rotates" ? Maybe, there's something being lost in these tiny comment boxes, but I don't really see any clarity problem with "the user to rotate around any single axis".

Comment: @WhyWhat - That quote from an ngrams ref ("You can allow the user to rotate around any single axis or pair of axes") is ambiguous for reasons not the same as the question asks about.  The quote writer probably meant that a user can rotate an object about an axis, but instead says that the user itself can rotate about an axis, or says something else entirely, regarding rotation of axes. 
   My intent was to suggest that "rotate around" instances are more often associated with muddled thinking than are "rotate about" instances, for which the quote is a relevant example.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure if this is a well-defined and widely accepted difference, but to me, "Rotate about" implies that the object is *spinning in place* (i.e. the defined axis passes through the center of the object in question, or at least through some internal point of the object), while "rotate around" implies that the object is *orbiting an external point*.

Comment: Of course, when the axis is defined, the preposition makes little difference.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

I think this picture should be helpful. It's a pretty good explanation!

Comment: Where did the picture come from? If it's your own work, you might save space by rendering the information as regular text and identifying a reference work that corroborates your definitions of "rotates around" and "rotates about." If the picture comes from someone else, please cite the source in your answer.

Comment: Moreover, pasting images of text is poor practice, and rather unfriendly to our visitors using screen readers. Please transcribe text rather than posting pictures of it.

Comment: My main problem with this answer is the expressions "...should be helpful" and "It's a[n] (...) explanation". Also, in the fig's top left corner, the word "Typically" is shown.  Where is the citation of source(s) for this answer?